# Ignore first and last line in file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to replace characters in certain columns of multiple text files using PowerShell. I have it working perfectly except that I need to ignore the first and the last row in each file and I can't get that to work.

This is what I have so far:

```
$Location = "C:\Users\gerhardl\Documents\Tenacity\TEMP\POWERSHELL TESTS"
$Data = "$Location\*.TXT"
$Output = "$Location\Fixed"

Get-Item $Data |
    ForEach-Object {
        $file = $_
        $_ | 
            Get-Content | 
            ForEach-Object {
                $Beginning = $_.Substring(0,105)
                $Account = $_.Substring(105,20) -replace "[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]", " "
                $End = $_.Substring(125)
                '{0}{1}{2}' -f $Beginning,$Account,$End
            } |
            Set-Content -Path (Join-Path $Output  $file.Name)

    }
```

I know there are similar threads, but it seems that my For Each loop doesn't play well with those suggestions.

Comment: Do want to drop the first and last line or keep them unchanged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tracking the first line is possible with a bool for each file `$IsFirstLine = $True` and then setting it to false inside the ForEach-Object. But tracking the last line, I think, is impossible with your pipeline method - you've already processed the last line before you know that it was the last one.

So you'd need another loop to count the lines or a buffer to be able to undo the changes on the last line once you identified it.

If the files are small enough to read into memory, maybe you could use an approach like:

```
$Location = "C:\Users\gerhardl\Documents\Tenacity\TEMP\POWERSHELL TESTS"
$Data = "$Location\*.TXT"
$Output = "$Location\Fixed"

Get-Item $Data | ForEach-Object {                   # for each file..

    $Lines = @(Get-Content $_.FullName)             # read all the lines, force array.
    $LinesToProcess = $Lines[1..($Lines.Count - 1)] # get lines except first and last.

    $ProcessedLines = $LinesToProcess | ForEach-Object {    # for each line..

        $Beginning = $_.Substring(0,105)
        $Account = $_.Substring(105,20) -replace "[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]", " "
        $End = $_.Substring(125)
        '{0}{1}{2}' -f $Beginning,$Account,$End

    }

    $OutputLines = $Lines[0] + $ProcessedLines + $Lines[-1] # add original first and last

    $OutputLines | Set-Content -Path (Join-Path $Output $_.Name)

}
```

Comment: Could I maybe be as forward as to as you to amend the answer to include my code as well? I'm trying to make this work but can't get it right - I'm a total newbie with PS and my skill consists of bastardizing other scripts together... keep in mind I have separate text files that need to be written out to the same separate filenames.

Comment: I've only sketched it out, not tried it; but I've put your code in and made a couple of tweaks as well.

Comment: This is now writing out the files but seems to have removed all line breaks.

Comment: Oh; make `$OutputLines = $Lines[0] +` into `$OutputLines = @($Lines[0]) +`

Answer (score 6):

You can use `-Skip 1` and `-SkipLast 1` :

```
Get-Content $file  | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Select-Object -SkipLast 1
```

**Edit for PS < 5 :**

```
$text = Get-Content $file | Select-Object -Skip 1
$newText = $text.GetRange(0,($text.Count - 1))
$newText
```

Comment: The v5 solution is great, but the v4- solution doesn't work, because `$text` is an array (`[System.Object[]]`), and arrays don't have a `.GetRange()` method.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Note: This post answers the generic question of **how to exclude the first and last line of an input file / an input collection from processing**.</sup>

[Manu's helpful `... | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Select-Object -SkipLast 1` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44528108/45375) works great in **PSv5+** (assuming the first and last line should be *eliminated* from the output).

However, their **PSv4- solution** doesn't work  (as of this writing), because the array (`[System.Object[]]` instance) returned by `Get-Content $file | Select-Object -Skip 1` doesn't have a `.GetRange()` method.
Here's a working solution that uses PowerShell's range operator (`..`):

```
# Read lines of the input file into an array.
$allLines = Get-Content $file
# Using the range operator (..), get all elements except the first and the last.
$allLines[1..([Math]::Max(1, $allLines.Count-2))]
```

<sup>Note:

* Trying `[1..-1]` is tempting, but does *not* work in PowerShell, because `1..-1` evaluates to subscripts `1, 0, -1`.

* If you know that there are at least *3* input objects, you can omit the `[Math]::Max()` call.</sup>

The above solution, however, is not always an option, because it **requires collecting all input objects *in memory* first**, which **negates the memory-throttling, one-by-one processing that a *pipeline*-based solution offers**.
(Although the in-memory solution, if feasible, is *faster*.)

To address that in **PSv4-**, you can **emulate `Select-Object -SkipLast 1`** in a ***pipeline-friendly* manner** as follows (`Select-Object -Skip 1` - skipping from the *start* - *is* supported in PSv4-).

```
# 'one', 'two', 'three' is a sample array. Output is 'one', 'two'
'one', 'two', 'three' | ForEach-Object { $notFirst = $False } { 
  if ($notFirst) { $prevObj }; $prevObj = $_; $notFirst = $True
}
```

Output of each input object is delayed by one iteration, which effectively omits the last one.

Here's the **generalization to `-SkipLast <n>`, implemented as advanced function `Skip-Last`**, which uses a [`[System.Collections.Generic.Queue[]]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1) instance to delay output by `<n>` objects:

```
# Works in PSv2+
# In PSv5+, use `Select-Object -SkipLast <int>` instead.
Function Skip-Last {
  <#
  .SYNOPSIS
    Skips the last N input objects provided.
    N defaults to  1.
  #>
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [ValidateRange(1, 2147483647)] [int] $Count = 1,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, ValueFromPipeline = $True)]$InputObject
  )

  begin { 
    $mustEnumerate = -not $MyInvocation.ExpectingInput # collection supplied via argument
    $qeuedObjs = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.Queue[object] $Count
  }
  process {
    # Note: $InputObject is either a single pipeline input object or, if
    #       the -InputObject *parameter* was used, the entire input collection.
    #       In the pipeline case we treat each object individually; in the
    #       parameter case we must enumerate the collection.
    foreach ($o in ((, $InputObject), $InputObject)[$mustEnumerate]) {
      if ($qeuedObjs.Count -eq $Count) {
        # Queue is full, output its 1st element.
        # The queue in essence delays output by $Count elements, which 
        # means that the *last* $Count elements never get emitted.
        $qeuedObjs.Dequeue()  
      }
      $qeuedObjs.Enqueue($o)
    }
  }
}
```

<sup>Note: In the `ValidateRange()` attribute above, `2147483647` is used instead of `[int]::MaxValue`, because PSv2 only supports *constants* in this case.</sup>

Sample call:

```
PS> 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five' | Skip-Last 3
one
two
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this as follows - not exactly what I posted but couldn't make that work. The first and last lines (header and trailer records) are much shorter in length so I did the following:

```
$Location = "C:\Users\gerhardl\Documents\Tenacity\TEMP\POWERSHELL TESTS"
$Data = "$Location\*.TXT"
$Output = "$Location\Fixed"

Get-Item $Data |
    ForEach-Object {
        $file = $_
        $_ | 
            Get-Content | 
            ForEach-Object {
            if ($_.length -gt 30)
            { 

                $Beginning = $_.Substring(0,105)
                $Account = $_.Substring(105,20) -replace "[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]", " "
                $End = $_.Substring(125)
                '{0}{1}{2}' -f $Beginning,$Account,$End
            }
            ELSE {
                $All = $_.Substring(0)
                '{0}' -f $All
                 }

            } |

            Set-Content -Path (Join-Path $Output  $file.Name)

    }
```